# Static Analysis Tool to generate report

Tags: static-analysis

I want to know if there are OSS of Static Analysis tool that can generate a report automatically.

I want to analyze the results / contents of the static analysis tool and automatically generate a report for the 
customer, but I leave it in Excel as a database of report templates, but visually confirm the result of exhaling 
the tool and relate from above Excel

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com/) for C/C++ or [JArchitect](https://www.jarchitect.com/) for Java, both offer the possibility to generate [reports](https://www.cppdepend.com/buildprocess) about your projects and also export results into Excel.